# What's the right way to store all kinds of Qt stuff in memory?

Tags: qt4

I'm trying to implement a global settings object, that save/load arbitrary Qt object,

But I'm wondering if this is the right way of doing so, as I only would store associated QString, QList, QSet (containers),

```
QObject *get (const QString & key);
void save (const QString & key, QObject *value);
```

With a internal hash table `QHash<QString,QObject*>`.

Is this the "official" way ?

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides serialization out of box only for QVariant types. For example, [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/) library handle that behavior. But you can call Q_DECLARE_METATYPE for every needed class to register it in QVariant. So, user-defined QVariant stored as raw bytes. If you want something more redable and specific in output format, than you should implement QDataStream input (>>) and output (<<) operators.